# Audio files are played faster than normal speed

Tags: sound

when I play some audio files, like university lectures, Ubuntu plays them at a higher speed.
Can anyone help?
Cheers

Comment: Which player? Have you tried an alternative player?

Answer (score 2):

The player you use will make an assumption about the *sample rate*, but this being a university lecture, it may have been sampled at a lower rate, resulting in lower sound quality.

You may want to resample the audio files, using full GUI software like Audacity or a terminal command like `sox`. Or you can try a different audio player like `VLC` that recognizes the lower sample rate and plays the file at the proper speed.